# C++ Xcode Library - Undeclared math.h features

Tags: c++, xcode

I have recently attempted to switch my C++ project's target from an executable to a  dynamic library (.dylib), and as soon as I rebuilt with the new target, I get a few errors saying that some defines and declarations in math.h are undeclared, such as `M_PI` and the `sqrt()` function.

The error message is as follows: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'M_PI'`, and `error: use of undeclared identifier 'sqrt'`

This only occurs when I am building my project as a library, and I cannot figure out why it is doing this.

If anyone can help me out on this, it would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**

Also, if I try to change my include to `#include <cmath>`, I get more errors, such as: `No member named 'signbit' in the global namespace`.

Comment: Actually including the text of the error message you are receiving makes it much easier to address your question.

Comment: `M_PI` is not Standard C++. It will only be there if the compiler implementers decide to put it there as an add-on. Can't help you with a missing `sqrt`. Never seen that before.

Comment: As @DonSimon mentioned, the actual error message would be helpful. The c-lib `math.h`, and the updated `cmath` are usually pretty widely used, and well used. `M_PI` is non-standard, as mentioned, but `sqrt` is very popular.

Comment: The error messages I get are up there, unless there's something else you'd like me to include. I really don't have anything else to go on... just that this only happens when I'm compiling as a library.

Comment: You say "I have read online that I should add `-lm` to my linker flags, but to no avail." Are these linker errors or compiler errors?

Comment: These are compiler errors... sorry, that was a silly thing to say.

Comment: It's weird that standard headers would fail when changing build type.

Comment: I've found that I compile successfully if I remove all of my headers from the headers build phase for my library target. But this removes all headers from my generated include folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `#include <cmath>` is at the top of the code, above `int main()`. I had the same problem. moving the `#include <cmath>` below `<iostream>` and above `int main()` solved the problem for me.